# how can I log the session with byobu

Tags: byobu

I would like to log session with byobu.
I wen through the configuration files but I could not see anything like log session etc. 
I want byobu to log my session as soon as launch it with date. :)

Comment: If you're using the screen backend, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114206/log-output-of-gnu-screen-in-real-time, and if the tmux backend, something from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/is-there-an-equivalent-of-gnu-screens-log-command-in-tmux might be useful.

Comment: Thanks @muru for your valuable answers. Indeed I can also use `screen` however for the moment shitt + F7 solves my requirement better so I mark down @dustin's answer as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions are automatically logged (up to 10,000 lines per windows).

You can "scrollback" any time by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PgDn</kbd>.  Note that you're in "vi mode", so you can also search for strings using <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>?</kbd>.  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit.

Now, you can also save that window to a file by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>, which will write the buffer to `$BYOBU_RUN_DIR/printscreen`.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.org).*

Comment: Sorry, deleted the sentence fragment.  Shouldn't have been there ;-)

Comment: Thank you Dustin for the answer. Do you have future plans to develop to add an option where we can set the flag and each time we start byobu it starts writing log to a file?  Another question is it possible to increase the buffer more than 10000 lines? Thanks

Comment: Actually, as of Byobu 5.116, it logs 100K lines per window.  You can change this easily in your ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf by adding a line with "set-option -g history-limit 100000" or however many you like.

Comment: @DustinKirkland does it autoreload this setting in an existing byobu session?