# log everything from a byobu session

Tags: logging, byobu, tmux

I am looking for a way how to preserve all console input and output of byobu sessions.

I am aware of these questions:

[How to save scrollback history in byobu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/382750/how-to-save-scrollback-history-in-byobu?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[how can I log the session with byobu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969796/how-can-i-log-the-session-with-byobu)

However I don't want to save the screenshot on demand, I want to have a log in case byobu crashes or the server reboots. Since this can happen at random times I won't be there to save the screenshot just before it happens. I assume the scroll back history is gone as soon as byobu is closed – at least I found no way of recovering it.

Ideally there would be also the possibility of a configurable log rotation of some kind to avoid outrageous log file sizes.

Basically I want to be sure that I can always see what happend just before the crash. Probably there would be one log file per open window and maybe one folder per session.

If this is not possible the next best fall back solution would be to write the scrollback buffer to disk in case of the OS asking byobu to quit (in case of reboot)

Comment: Have you seen muru's comment https://askubuntu.com/questions/969796/how-can-i-log-the-session-with-byobu#comment1553346_969796 ? It has two useful pointers.